# Could not load NIB in bundle: NSBundle with name '2-view-5' and directory 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc''

Tags: ios

Please give me idea about this error? 2-view-5 is what how can i find it?

2013-11-01 21:50:20.879 coffee break app[4107:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name '2-view-5' and directory 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc''

Comment: Did a you typo a `c` somewhere when you were loading a storyboard?

Comment: no.sometime it is a mistake.can you give me a idea to fixed this error